# setting up boot DVD

Tags: boot

I am interested in setting up a boot DVD, a DVD from which I can boot, containing a kernel which is compatible with Ubuntu.

Is this a reasonable thing to attempt?  Is there a command I can use which will generate such a DVD?

Comment: Making a custom iso is time consuming and requires a bit of reading, but if you can tell us what are you wanting to do exactly we can give better advice. Depending on your customizations you can use remastersys or my preference, for large modifications, is the debian live scripts (they work fine in ubuntu).

Comment: I just want to boot ubuntu but obtaining the kernel from the DVD. The other files come from the hard disk. Do you need any more info?

Comment: Do you know how to make a bootable DVD (if all you need is a kernel you could use a flash drive or CD as the iso is going to be much smaller then a 4 Gb DVD).

Comment: This is what I am asking, what ubuntu command to use to make a bootable DVD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "trivial" to do this.

1) Install the necessary packages

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux genisoimage
```

2) Make a working directory

```
mkdir -p DVD/isolinux
```

3) Move your kernel, initramfs, and `isolinux.bin` to the working directory

```
cp /boot/vmlinuz-your-kernel DVD/isolinux
cp /boot/initramfs-your-initramfs.img DVD/isolinux
cp /usr/lib/syslinux/isolinux.bin DVD/isolinux/
```

4) Create (write) a `isolinux.cfg` file, save it at `DVD/isolinux/isolinux.cfg`

```
DEFAULT live
LABEL live
menu label ^Ubuntu kernel , boot hard drive
kernel /isolinux/vmlinuz-your-kernel
INITRD /isolinux/initramfs-your-initramfs.img
append  root=/dev/your_root_partition ro quiet splash --
TIMEOUT 300
```

5) Make the iso

```
cd DVD
sudo mkisofs -r -V "Live-DVD" -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o ../ubuntu-dvd.iso .
cd ..
```

6) Burn the DVD, although it will fit on a flash drive or CD easily.

For additional information see

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Syslinux

The arch wiki page has great information on syslinux, and some splash and menu options I did not cover.